# Visual Studio Mac and VS2019 Xamarin do both not open Storyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin, storyboard, visual-studio-2019

I have a Xcode project. Just a simple dummy project that I use for compiling for VS2019 on my windows. VS2019 can't open the storyboard any more after I updated windows, vs2019 and Mac.
So I tried to run it on my Mac first, and should everything work I could try my VS2019 project again.

I also have Visual Studio for mac installed. When I create the same dummy project for my Xcode project the storyboard does not open in design mode.
I get the same error every time. The connection between my windows Xamarin project works. But also I get the same error here. The Storyboard won't open in design mode.

Mac :

> Error : Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted
>   VS2019 : Couldn't find a Devicelog for [ConnectionAttributes:Device=Undefined......

What have I tried already:

1. Everything is updated, no more updates are available.
2. I've removed all my devices in the simulator and added them back again.
3. I've opened my storyboard in Xcode and saved it.
4. I've removed my storyboard and added a new one.
5. Firewall is disabled, so that should not be a problem.

Xcode : 11.2.1 (11B500)
Visual Studio : 8.3.10 (build 2)
IOS : Catalina 10.15.1

Every forum, every site I've read already. A least that's how it feels.
I really could use some tips.

This is the complete error:

> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.)) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown.) ---> MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException: Exception of type 'MonoTouch.Design.Client.InvalidSessionException' was thrown. ---> Foundation.NSErrorException: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=165 "Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to erase contents and settings in current state: Booted}
>     at MonoTouch.Hosting.Device.ResetContentAndSettings () [0x0001d] in <04dc5ca6c35a46aa8bc6e6cd7c986dae>:0 
>     at MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac.MacServerProcessConnection.EnsureServerRunning (System.Boolean throwIfNotRunning) [0x000ff] in /Users/runner/runners/2.160.0/work/1/s/Xamarin.Designer.iOS/MonoTouch.Design.Client.Mac/MacServerProcessConnection.cs:298 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

And more but the number of characters is restricted.

Comment: Try to create a new project and check if the issue still exists . And delete the folder `bin` and `obj` , then clean and rebuild your project .

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. BUT I'm getting a new order now, that's something.

Comment: You could clean the caches in `Library->Developer->CoreSimulator->Caches` .If it still doesn't work , you could create a support ticket https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=72d637f5-ce08-008a-711f-9ba5aee0d93c .We will focus on it :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to install Mojave in stead of Catalina and reinstall everything. Keer both sides of the mac and pc sync.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the problem with the following command in terminal:

```
xcrun simctl shutdown all
```

**Update:** Seems like this issue starts when you force close apps. After two days of successful work I received the same message. I did command above, after that added `xcrun simctl erase all`, rebooted. Issue was still there. Finally I got how to fix it.

**Solution**: You should open xib, it will start spinning and during that open terminal and run `xcrun simctl shutdown all`. After that the issue will be resolved.